# Get first document from an embedded document in array - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, database

Here is collection data I'm working on.

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "embed_array" : [
        {
            "id" : 14,
            "data" : "XXX"
        },
        {
            "id" : 13,
            "data" : "YYY"
        },
        {
            "id" : 12,
            "data" : "ZZZ"
        }
    ]
}, 
{
    "_id" : "2",
    "embed_array" : [
        {
            "id" : 14,
            "data" : "XXX1"
        },
        {
            "id" : 13,
            "data" : "YYY1"
        },
        {
            "id" : 12,
            "data" : "ZZZ1"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : "3",
    "embed_array" : [
        {
            "id" : 14,
            "data" : "XXX2"
        },
        {
            "id" : 13,
            "data" : "YYY2"
        },
        {
            "id" : 12,
            "data" : "ZZZ2"
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is what I'm looking to get.

```
{
     "id" : 14,
     "data" : "XXX"
}
```

Here is search criteria. 
"_id": "1",
"embed_array": first array document.

I tried with $slice, but didn't get it work.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this :

```
db.collection.find({
   _id:"1"
},
{
   _id:1,
   embed_array:{
      $slice: 1
   }
})
```

first step is to filter on _id field with {_id: "1"}. Then we use projection to return only the information we need. Here, we want only the first element of "embed_array", so we use the **[$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/projection/slice/)** operator.

{$slice: 1} is equal to {$slice: [0,1]} which means: get element of the array between index 0 and 1

it will return

```
{ 
  "_id" : "1", 
  "embed_array" : [ 
    { "id" : 14, "data" : "XXX" } 
  ] 
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. can you explain it in more detail?

Comment: Thanks. I got an idea.

Comment: Hi @felix 
could you pls tell me how to get last element of the array instead of first element?